# Python Morse Code not working for phrases

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

I have this code:

```py
class Morse_Code_Bin_Tree(object):
    """Class that initializes and populates a binary tree for translating morse code strings into letters.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node("*")

        letters = "ETIANMSURWDKGOHVF*L*PJBXCYZQ**54*3***2**+****16=/*****7***8*90"

        current = self.head
        nexts = []

        for char in letters:
            if current.left == None:
                current.left = Node(char)
            else:
                if current.right == None:
                    current.right = Node(char)
                else:
                    nexts.append(current.left)
                    nexts.append(current.right)
                    current = nexts.pop(0)
                    current.left = Node(char)

    def translate_mc_to_letter(self, mc_ltr_str):
        """method that takes a string input of morse code, traverses the morse code binary tree, and returns the correct letter for that sequnce.
            e.g. "...." => "H"
        """
        current = self.head

        for char in mc_ltr_str:
            if char == ".":
                current = current.left
            else:
                current = current.right

        return current.val


class Node(object):
    """binary node"""
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.val = char
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

It works just fine is a try to decode only single letters, like below:

```
mc_tree = Morse_Code_Bin_Tree()
mc_tree.translate_mc_to_letter("....") # Prints Letter 'H'
```

But when I try to print 'HE'

```
mc_tree.translate_mc_to_letter(".... .")
```

...the code fails with this error:

```
return current.val
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
```

The binary tree that is created in the constructor looks like this:

[image]

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `translate_mc_to_letter` is only intended for returning *one* letter (cf. the method name). You should either create another method to call this one for every "word" in the input string, or do that directly in your main code:

```
s = "... --- ..."
print("".join(map(morse.translate_mc_to_letter, s.split())))  # SOS
```

If you prefer a method (notice the multiple forms with "s"):

```
def translate_mcs_to_letters(self, mcs_str):
    return "".join(map(morse.translate_mc_to_letter, mcs_str.split()))
```

And call as:

```
print(morse.translate_mcs_to_letters("... --- ..."))
```